# How to send image to web service node js and then execute stored procedure with this image parameter

Tags: sql-server, node.js, stored-procedures, http-request-parameters

I'm newbie node js. I wrote the following stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ADDMESSAGE]
    @PhoneNumber nvarchar(50),
    @Type numeric(18,0),
    @Image Image=null,
    @MessageContent nvarchar(255)=null
AS
BEGIN
    insert Message([PhoneNumber],[Type],[Image],[MessageContent])
    values(@PhoneNumber,@Type,@Image,@MessageContent)
    RETURN 1
END
```

My NodeJS Web Service:

```
app.post('/message/add',function(req,res){
    sql.close();
    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) 
            console.log(err);

        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.input('PhoneNumber',sql.NVarChar(50),req.query.phoneNumber);
        request.input('Type',sql.Numeric,req.query.type);
        //request.input('Image',sql.Image,req.query.image);
        //How to add image into SP???
        request.input('MessageContent',sql.NVarChar(225),req.query.messageContent);
        request.execute('SP_ADDMESSAGE').then(function(err,recordset,returnValue,affect){
            console.dir(recordset); 
            console.dir(err);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
});
```

But I don't know how to send http request POST with image in android (or use Postman application or HttpRequester in Firefox) to this web service, and how to add the image into parameter in stored procedure to execute.

Comment: once I tried using postman with files - it wasn't very smooth. I wrote small script, say integration test, that did exactly what I needed. Have a look at request npm module.

Answer (score 0):

Typically binary data, like images, aren't stored in the database. Storage at that level is expensive (relatively speaking) and isn't meant for that sort of thing.

Rather, images are stored on the file system as a renamed (extensionless) file and given a unique record in the database to represent them.

This record usually has:

- a uniquely generated id or uuid
- the file type
- the file name
- the file size
- date uploaded
- etc.

Some apps will optimize the image at this point, because let's face it camera's are insanely good these days and files are huge (I would highly recommend this).

To return the "image" to the app, you would generate a URL using the unique identifier from the database record I just mentioned. This would correspond to a path in the app OR an external CDN url if you've gone that direction instead. Speaking to the "in-app" approach. The app would lookup the record based on the key provided in the url (`yoursite.com/images/1`), subsequently grab the binary data from wherever it's stored and render it using a graphics library (nodejs has a version of the [GD library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gd) which I've use before).

Answer (score 0):

Look for gm module in nodejs. I implemented image upload in my project using gm. Everything is explained here https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm